# Why I receive a zero when I send a decimal?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I have two inputs for numbers (integer or decimal). If I send integers the app runs good, but if I send decimals, IDK why the app recive 0

Example: I have my **price** input, I write the value of **12.55**, when I do the request to save the number, in my controller that value appear like 0, so the DB save it with 0

I would like to know what is happening

This is my view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add concept</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
        <div style="visibility:hidden">
          <input type="text" id="mIdcon" disabled="disabled" />
          <input type="text" id="mIdreq" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label for="mCanti">Quantity</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    id="mCanti" placeholder="Quantity" 
                    onkeypress="return filterFloat(event, this);" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="Fent">Delivery Date:</label>
            <input type="text" class="datefield form-control" 
                    id="Fent" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label for="UDM">UDM / UOM</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mUDM" maxlength="2" 
                    placeholder="UDM / UOM" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="cCta">Acount</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("ctaMAX", null, new { 
              @id = "cCta", 
              @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", 
              @style = "color:#777777;background-color:#f8f8f8;border-color:#e7e7e7" })
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="Descripcion">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mDes" 
                    placeholder="Description" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="par">Partialities</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("parci", null, new { 
                @id = "par", 
                @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", 
                @style = "color:#777777;background-color:#f8f8f8;border-color:#e7e7e7" })
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label for="NoParte">Part Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mNopa" 
                    placeholder="Part Number" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label for="Precio">Unit Price</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mPrecio" 
                  placeholder="Unit Price" 
                  onkeypress="return filterFloat(event, this);" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" 
                onclick="return AddConcept();">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
function AddConcept() {
var res = Validate(); // This function just validate that the inputs aren't empty
if (res == false) {
    return false;
}

var ConceptoObj = {
    idconcepto: $('#mIdcon').val(),
    idreq: $('#idreq').val(),
    cantidad: $('#mCanti').val(),
    UDM: $('#mUDM').val(),
    descripcion: $('#mDes').val(),
    NoParte: $('#mNopa').val(),
    precio: $('#mPrecio').val(),
    FechaEntrega: $('#Fent').val(),
    PagoParcial: $('#par option:selected').val()
};
var c = $('#cCta').val();
var f = $('#fes').val();
var m = $('#mon').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Order/AddConcept?cta=' + c + '&fs=' + f + '&cm=' + m,
    data: JSON.stringify(ConceptoObj),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        CargarConceptosOC();
        AjusteRate();
        if (result == "-100")
            alert("-You have exceeded the limit of concepts for this Requisition-");
        if (result == "-200")
            alert("-There is a problem. Contact the admin-");
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

This is my controller:

```
public JsonResult AddConcept(ConceptosOC conOC, string cta, string fs, string cm)
{
    int resp = 0, idcon = 0;
    resp = objDB.CUDConceptosOC(conOC, 1);
    DateTime fesol = conOC.FechaEntrega == null 
                        ? DateTime.Today : (DateTime)conOC.FechaEntrega;
    DateTime fcenti;

    decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(
                    objDB.SelectCadena("Here I get the dolar price"));
    int renglon = Convert.ToInt32(
                    objDB.SelectCadena("Here I get the row that I want to modify"));

    if (resp == -1)
    {
        idcon = Convert.ToInt32(objDB.SelectCadena("Here I get a specific ID"));

        switch (conOC.PagoParcial)
        {
          case 2:
          // Ignore this
          break;
          default:
            resp = objDB.Ejecutar(
              "INSERT INTO ACOUNTS(ID_CONCEPT, ID_REQUEST, AMOUNT, ACOUNT, REGISTER_DATE, ROW_AFFECTED)" +
              "values(" + idcon + "," + conOC.idreq + "," + 
              ((conOC.cantidad * conOC.precio) * rate).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
              ",'" + cta + "','" + fesol.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + 
              "'," + (renglon + 1) + ")");
            break;
        }
    }
    return Json(resp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my object:

```
public class ConceptosOC
{
    public int idconcepto { get; set; }
    public int idreq { get; set; }
    public decimal cantidad { get; set; }
    public string UDM { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string NoParte { get; set; }
    public decimal precio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public int PagoParcial { get; set; }

}
```

Those are my filter functions:

```
function filterFloat(evt, input) {
var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
var tempValue = input.value + chark;
if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
    if (filter(tempValue) === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    if (key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (key == 46) {
        if (filter(tempValue) === false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}}


function filter(__val__) {
var preg = /^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,4})$/;
if (preg.test(__val__) === true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: What is the culture on your server? Is it one that expects a `.` (dot) as a decimal separator? (some of your code suggests Spanish, so if that is you culture you would need to enter `12,55` (comma) or change the culture in the app, or create a custom ModelBinder

Comment: Unrelated tip: get out of the habit of using string concatenation to create queries, since it makes them vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and other issues, like string values containing apostrophes, or your numeric amount using ToString G , which could end up giving you a value containing a comma in a comma-separated list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably receiving 0 because it is the default value for your model. That means your application was not able to bind the received value to your model because it was unabled to translate it back to a C# model. This might be related to the way your server has the culture configured. You are sending ***12.55***, and your server might be expecting something like "***12,55***" if it is configured in French or Spanish, for example. You could try to modify your model binding for decimal values by using a custom model binder that implements ***System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder***.
You could try something like this. Define a custom model binder

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;  

public class CustomDecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the decimal value from data received
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">Controller context</param>
    /// <param name="bindingContext">Binding context</param>
    /// <returns>Parsed value</returns>
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                            System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        var modelState = new System.Web.Mvc.ModelState { 
                                        Value = result 
                                    };

        object actualValue = null;
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        if (result.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                // Try with your current culture
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(result.AttemptedValue, culture);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Try with invariant culture if current culture failed
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(result.AttemptedValue, 
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    modelState.Errors.Add(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Use it in your Application_Start method

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // ... normal MVC configuration code

    // This one binds Decimal types
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new CustomDecimalModelBinder ());
    // This one binds Nullable Decimal types, if you want to support those also
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new CustomDecimalModelBinder ());
}
```